# Legal to leave electrical boxes open and hanging by contractor

Tags: electrical

My contractor (fired) left electrical boxes open with components no longer screwed into the boxes. Is this illegal?

I discovered after I fired the contractor that he is unlicensed. I am compiling a list of issues for arbitration and maybe litigation.

I hired a general contractor that hires subcontractors. The subcontractor in this instance is the GC's son. This is supposed to be a company and not DIY.

I guess the questions are:

- Should this be reported to the electrical board?
- Is it normal to leave the receptacles like this for weeks?
- Does this need an electrician to allow me to utilize the room until I
  can hire another company who uses licensed contractors?

[image: open and hanging electrical components]

The list is quite long as to why we fired the contractor. I've noted some reasons as a comment to a below comment.

Comment: This is a remodel of my home where I'm currently living. They were not waiting for any inspections. They were doing everything from sanding, demo, backsplash, electrical, plumbing by 1 guy. We had a long list of issues that they were not willing to correct. Thus we fired them. They left me without a kitchen sink as well. I hired a licensed master plumber to install the sink, valves, piping and faucet. This photo is of my kitchen that we need to use day to day.

Comment: The contractors left it like this for 2 weeks before being fired.

Comment: Was it his job to pull the permit?  Or was the plan all along to do it on the sly?

Comment: Do yourself a favor: if the power is turned on, get them mounted in the boxes. (Either you or a handyman. If it's you, find some ~1" 6-32 machine screws, turn off the power to the whole house, and wrestle them into place.)

Comment: I suspect they were going to do everything on the sly. No mention ever of permitting.

Comment: I was not sure if I should do the work mounting them or bringing in someone to see what was left. I need the plugs and the light switches though.

Answer (score 2):

The room does not appear move-in ready.  Perhaps it was "left" like that because an inspection is a next step here, e.g. By the licensed electrician he'd have brought in to sign off on the work if you hadn't fired him, or by the city inspector.

Much of what electricians do is such as wiring compressor buildings in refineries, fitting main and backup power in data centers, at a mall putting in 800kva (that's more than the whole mall) of 480/3ph service to power a dozen Tesla chargers, installing mad numbers of Tesla PowerWalls for people not content with their grid-dependent systems, etc.  Those things *need* experienced electricians and are outbidding residential builders for the limited supply of electricians.

As such, it's a seller's market in this building boom.  Booms tend to cause the bottom of the barrel to be scraped, creating employ for licensed electricians who aren't very good and can't get work except in these times.

**Having an apprentice wire outlets then a competent electrician inspects is perfectly reasonable**, and certainly preferable to the alternative of hiring one of those bottom-of-the-barrel types, insisting an incompetent do your wiring merely because he's blessed with a government medallion.

Of course, I'm biased; I am one of those competent-but-unlicensed types... but I'm not paid to wire.

Comment: I assume you would not leave the electric boxes like this for 2+ weeks while the homeowner is living in the home. Some boxes are not far from a sink. I understand apprentices. This person was not an apprentice, no one was going to inspect. The guy punched a hole in my wall into another room when doing demo. The incompetent type was what we had working in our home.

Comment: @slwf Sorry, but that's an artifact of our Q&A format. I was answering the original question which didn't include that detail.  Honestly, I detect a certain desire here to also vent/rant/commiserate; the Q&A format is rather bad for that.  It works much better on forums/message boards,  such as diychatroom.com.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen (and done) this for so many years I can't count them anymore. Leave them like this for an inspection and then wait for the drywall installation before screwing them all back in... I give the guy credit for the nail plates.

Comment: The nail plates were there from the builder. This is a remodel. No inspection was ever scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

If you "fired" him before he finished, or if you fired him because he *did not* finish, it is not per code to call what I see in the picture as a "finished" job...

Inspections are done in a "rough" ( what is seen in the picture ) and a "final" ( when done ) sequence.

You could not get a "ok to occupy" because the job *isn't finished..*  Again, I don't know the circumstance in which you fired, but either way, the word "illegal" would be something decided in a court, if you wanted to pursue that avenue. 
Bottom line:
The cops can't inspect that unfinished job and arrest the guy based upon him exiting the premises, for whatever reason.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but couldn't this have passed a rough inspection and the outlets are hanging, waiting for the drywall installation?

Comment: @Jack this person didn't mention if any permits were pulled or not. As always ( in this DYI realm ) you never know.

Comment: No permits were ever mentioned. This area is in my kitchen. The hardibacker was installed the day after this photo but the electric is still like the photo. This area will be backsplash at some point.

Comment: Just curious if you'd like to reveal.. Why did you fire him ?

Comment: Long list. Poor sanding leaving gashes, dents and wavy sections of cabinets, These were painted over before repairing. The new counter was badly cut where the sink is not aligning properly. Hole punched through a wall into my living room during backsplash demo, leaving electric boxes like this for 2+ weeks, caused a water leak that damaged the bottom cabinet under my sink, failed to plastic curtain off the room so dust went all over the home, no tarp on the floor where dust has accumulated in the grout and cant be scrubbed out. Dust left behind appliances. & more

Comment: Oh the guy was a " I can do it all" kind of guy ? Okay that makes sense.

Comment: Exactly. I asked early on about additional contractors. The one doing all of the work was going to do it all including electrical and plumbing. He was the doer and his boss the general contractor project manager showed up occasionally. The contractor was to also add a receptacle to plug in a new microwave. The wiring was from a hard wired vent hood. Thus he would be adding a new box.

Comment: I think I used the word "illegal" instead of whatever word is needed to file a complaint to the electrical board. They would need to handle what they do with unlicensed people doing work for someone else.

Comment: Ok got it. Since this is a dyi site, that happens. The term "not up to code " is pretty commonly use ( accurate) phrase ...Whatever state you live in there's usually a state contractor's license board.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/sKKQyPrqZcgYocsn6

Comment: The above is some work some local house flippers did in our neighborhood. Some neighbors told me about it and wanted to ask if I'd go over there and look to see "if it was up to code" after a couple days of work ( before the drywall went back up ) Atrocious ! They got busted, and they were not licensed to do the work, FYI

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is if these wires were not terminated in the panel and have no voltage on them this is ok. Not professional, but ok.  If they are hot, this is a huge liability.  Proper rough-in is to make the boxes ready for termination, but do not terminate until after the wall covering is on.  Terminating devices, before say drywall, is poor workmanship because drywall dust gets in the device and can make for a poor connection later on. I am a former electrical inspector.

Comment: These are wires are hot. Dust is in the receptacles.

Comment: To be safe, you should either have the wire removed from the breaker or if you need power in the room to work, remove all receptacles except the first one in the circuit and fasten it to the box put a cover on it.  If you do any of this work yourself be sure to turn off the breaker first.